# Flush AudioTrack in Xamarin.Android in an async way

Tags: c#, xamarin, audio, xamarin.android, audiotrack

AudioTrack.Flush doesn't finish his work, I found out that while AudioTrack is flushing (in an other thread), if I write some data, it stop flush, so I tried to lock AudioTrack while is flushing (no changes), so I tried to ignore the writing of data while AudioTrack is flushing with a simple sleep of 100ms and it works, I suppose that AudioTrack.Flush create a new Thread that flush the buffer, but somebody can explain me this (for me) strange behaviour?
P.S. data to write in the buffer has lenght one sample and is spammed (from UDP dgrams)
P.s: audioTrack = new AudioTrack(Android.Media.Stream.Music, 16000, ChannelOut.Mono, Android.Media.Encoding.Pcm16bit, 8, AudioTrackMode.Stream, 0);

```
new Thread(() =>
{
    while(true)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        canwrite_to_buffer = false;
        audioTrack.Flush();
        Thread.Sleep(100);
        canwrite_to_buffer = true;
    }
}).Start();
```

Comment: you can edit your existing post

Comment: Is your stream playing when you call `Flush`?

Comment: yes it is always playing, is a stream

Comment: That is a problem then, flushing is not happening, from the API: `...No-op if not stopped or paused,....`

Comment: I tried to pause the audiotrack before the flushing and replay then, but the behaviour doesn't change, if I write in the buffer while it is flushing, he seems to stop flushing. IN the end with the "canwrite_to_buffer" checker it works, though audiotrack is not stopped or paused

Comment: You might want to read the API notes for `flush`: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioTrack#flush()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution: When try to write some data into AudioTrack stream while is flushing, it stop flushing, so I have to wait while is flushing, I didn't find a way flush in an async way with callback or in a sync way, so I wait for about 100ms, but it isn't the best solution